# Facial Expression Recognition on Android

Tags: android, camera, face-recognition

My first Android app is going to involve a front facing camera, and facial expression recognition. I did a lot of research, yet I couldn't find any Android libraries that involve any facial expression recognition. I basically want to measure reactions.

I'm thinking it MUST have been done somewhere in some app, can anyone point my research in the right direction? If not in Android, perhaps somebody may know of a library that I can port over?

Comment: It's vastly more complex that you think.

Comment: I imagine you're going to probably find a java library that you can use on Android. Instead of one you build specifically for android. And I think it is unlikely that you'll find a very good library without spending any money for it. This will be a very tough first project. Unless you have lots of experience on other platforms I would suggest taking on something a little bit easier in order to get the hang of Android.

Comment: I'm pretty confident I can figure it out. Given a set of data from a recognition engine that is, I can most likely find patterns - there's plenty of papers on it... I'm not at a level where I could write my own image recognition code, but I can most definitley interpret data from one. Any relevant Java stuff you can refer me to? I wasn't aware Java libraries work in Android, guess I should really be learning more about the platform its self. I'm looking at OpenCV now, but any other leads would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi @KaviSiegel, have you find one solution for this problem? Can you help me? I have to recognize facial expressions on android too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest getting the [Android OpenCV port](http://code.google.com/p/android-opencv/) working as a good first step.

Due to real-time requirements for image processing, most of the face detection/recognition code you're going to see is likely to be in C++. Many systems may use OpenCV as a base and/or you can cobble together a reasonable solution from OpenCV's many low-level functions.

The CVCamera sample in there is also good for showing how JNI/NDK interop works on Android which can be helpful for interfacing with other code.

Answer (score 1):

what about [face.com?](http://face.com/) it's web(service) based, but supposed to be pretty good!

Comment: It looks like face.com may be pretty good for picking out faces, and it looks like they can pick out a smile... but as to general "facial expression recognition", I don't think so.

Comment: face.com, broken link....