# Camera Record , capture image, facedetection ,in background user can not see app is capturing him in android?

Tags: android, background, camera, face-detection

i have one tricky concept.i don't understand it is possible or not.

What i want ?

i have one application which are displaying images and video continue.
now i want to start camera in this application background and
i want to check how many people are see this images and video.
how long time people see this image/video in seconds or minute with person wise and store in database.detect people is happy,angry,people like this, people don't like this person is male/female person age. using face detection.

Suggestion Welcome!!!!

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facial Expression Recognition on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833922/facial-expression-recognition-on-android)

Comment: not it is the different one i also calculate seconds for people see image video