# Any Mood or Emotions Detection apis for Android?

Tags: android

I need to detect user's mood (sad, happy etc) with the help of device's front camera, so Is there any APIs or SDKs available for Android to detect user's mood or emotions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facial Expression Recognition on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833922/facial-expression-recognition-on-android)

Answer (score 4):

Google Play Services 7.8+ has a [Face API](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/face-detection-in-google-play-services.html) that lets you determine whether the user is smiling or not, depending on your requirements that might be a suitable choice.